# Безопасно ли использование данной функции

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

```
#define N 20

char* fun(char *s){
scanf("\n");
int i = 0, n = 1;
char c = getchar();
while (c != '\n'){
    s[i] = c; i++;
    c = getchar();
    if (i >= (n*N - 1)){
        n++;
        s = (char*)realloc(s, n*N*sizeof(char));
    }
}
s[i] = '\0';
return s;
}
...

char *str = (char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char));
str = fun(str);
```

Насколько нормально данное перевыделение памяти и затем присваивание переменной возвращаемого значения

#

Заметил что данная функция чтения и записи строки работает не так, как хотелось бы к примеру строка (для наглядность пробел это _  ) "Привет___" считывается как нужно, то есть "Привет___", а строка по типу "___Привет" как "Привет", в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: что плохого в realloc?

Comment: Возможно что-то делаю не так не с realloc, а с перевыделением в функции и присваиванием возвращаемого значения (всё работает, но хотелось бы быть уверенным на 100%, что работает  это всё не на соплях или везении)

Comment: Плохо понимаю людей минусующих это вопрос. Человек хочет научится - от меня "+"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Проверять успешность `malloc` и `realloc` - надо. Выполнять явное приведение типа на их результаты - не надо.
2. Ваша функция предполагает, что снаружи было заранее выделено именно `N` байтов памяти. Это криво. Не надо ничего предполагать. Если вы выделяли память снаружи, то передавайте ее размер в функцию явно.

   Но здесь вообще не понятно, зачем вы выделяли память снаружи. Зачем? Почему бы не выделять ее внутри функции?
3. Вы сами сделали вызов `scanf("\n");` в начале своей функции, т.е. попросили стандартную библиотеку *пропустить все пробельные символы* во входном потоке. Неудивительно, что строка "___Привет" после этого читается как "Привет".

Comment: char *str = fun(str);
char* fun(char *s){
 scanf("\n");
 s = (char*)malloc(N*sizeof(char));
        ...
вы хотели сказать об этом, это допустимо?

Comment: @Jujelica: Допустимо. Только вашей функции по сути вообще не нужен параметр. `char *fun(void){...}... char *str = fun();`, и все.

Comment: Спасибо, возможно вы знаете, почему функция считывает символы не так, как хотелось бы, (см. дополнение к вопросу) был бы очень благодарен за хоть какой-то намёк как это исправить, ради  интереса пробовал fgets, но результат тот же